# How to click on a button with a data-elementid in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

How to click on a button with a data-elementid in Puppeteer?

The website has this:

```
<button class="M-r MB-r j3 Mn-cy" tabindex="0" type="button" data-elementid="searchButton">
```

I'm trying to click the button:

```
const selector = '#searchButton';
await page.waitForSelector(selector);
await page.click(selector);
```

I've tried waiting 10 seconds to make sure the page was fully loaded.

Receiving the error:

```
TimeoutError: waiting for selector `#searchButton`
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `#` is for an id, `data-elementid` is different to an id attribute. Try and use the selector `'[data-elementid="searchButton"]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the selector.

This:

```js
const selector = '#searchButton';
```

translates into this in html:

```html
id="searchButton"
```

but you're looking for `data-elementid="searchButton"` attribute.

Try this instead:

```
const selector = '[data-elementid="searchButton"]';
```